# apache alias and relative urls

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mod-vhost-alias

I have made a new website for a customer. Before we put it online he wants to see it.
Now, I have server, so I thought of putting it in a subdirectory: `http://localhost/project2`

I added this to the vhost:

```
Alias /project2 /home/sites/www/project2
<Directory /home/sites/www/project2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is working fine, when I go to `http://localhost/project2`

the site is loaded.
Only the css, javascript, ... are not loaded because they are still pointing to the main url

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

Loads `http://localhost/js/jquery.lightbox.min.js`

Also, when I post a form, my action is e.g. /contact, it refers to `http://localhost/contact`

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: You need to change all your links/actions/src to relative URLs, there's no easy way to solve this.